# Postgresql combine IN with NOT IN

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of entities where each can have different statuses. For the sake of keeping history, each status change is reflected by a new row.
Example:

```
Entity Id      Status  
123456         1    
123456         2  
789000         1
```

Assuming i want to find all rows that have only status 1 (so if they have other statuses they should not be returned), How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
select entityid
from tablename
group by entityid
having min(status) = 1 and max(status) = 1
```

returns all the `entityid`s that you want, so you can use it with the operator `IN`:

```
select * from tablename
where entityid in (
  select entityid
  from tablename
  group by entityid
  having min(status) = 1 and max(status) = 1 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.entity_id = t.entity_id and t2.status <> 1
                 );
```

Comment: @karellahmy . . .  That should be status, not `entity_id` for the comparison.